# C++ multiple returns from single function

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

still pretty new to C++. 
Had to write a function in class to count the number of each digit in a multi-dimensional array. 
Now I didn't think you could return multiple `int` values from a single called function and then use all of these returns in a text based answer, so I attempted to `return` a different value depending on the value requested as parameter for each digit.

The code below is unnecessarily long and I'm still receiving the following errors.

```
main-1-3.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main-1-3.cpp:12:21: error: too few arguments to function 'int 
count_numbers(int(*)[4], int)'
count_numbers(array);
                 ^
main-1-3.cpp:7:12: note: declared here
extern int count_numbers(int array[4][4], int);
```

With a bit of debugging I could likely fix up these compile errors, but I feel like my method is extremely convoluted and was wondering if it were possible to call the function as:

```
count_number(array[4][4])
```

(Removing the need for the Q parameter) and then have `count_numbers`return all ten of the number values and the just output them as text like `<< ",3:" << three <<` instead of `<< ",8:" << count_numbers(array, 8) <<`

Anyway, the function.cpp and main.cpp are below. 
If anyone could point me in the right direction it would greatly appreciated. Just need to know the correct method so I can condense this code.

**function.cpp**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int count_numbers(int array[4][4], int Q)
{
    int X=0;
    int Y=0;
    int zero=0;
    int one=0;
    int two=0;
    int three=0;
    int four=0;
    int five=0;
    int six=0;
    int seven=0;
    int eight=0;
    int nine=0;
while(X<4)
{
    if(array[X][Y]==0)
    {
        zero=zero+1;
    }
    if(array[X][Y]==1)
    {
        one=one+1;
    }
    if(array[X][Y]==2)
    {
        two=two+1;
    }
    if(array[X][Y]==3)
    {
        three=three+1;
    }
    if(array[X][Y]==4)
    {
        four=four+1;
    }
    if(array[X][Y]==5)
    {
        five=five+1;
    }
    if(array[X][Y]==6)
    {
        six=six+1;
    }
    if(array[X][Y]==7)
    {
        seven=seven+1;
    }
    if(array[X][Y]==8)
    {
        eight=eight+1;
    }
    if(array[X][Y]==9)
    {
        nine=nine+1;
    }
    Y++;
    if(Y==4)
    {
        Y=0;
        X++;
    }
}


if(Q==0)
{
    return zero;
}
if(Q==1)
{
    return one;
}
if(Q==2)
{
    return two;
}
if(Q==3)
{
    return three;
}
if(Q==4)
{
    return four;
}
if(Q==5)
{
    return five;
}
if(Q==6)
{
    return six;
}
if(Q==7)
{
    return seven;
}
if(Q==8)
{
    return eight;
}
if(Q==9)
{
    return nine;
}

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

extern int count_numbers(int array[4][4], int);

int array[4][4] = { {1,2,3,4} , {1,2,3,4} , {1,2,3,4} , {1,2,3,4}};
int main()
{
count_numbers(array);
std::cout << ",0:" << count_numbers(array, 0) << ",1:" << count_numbers(array, 1) << ",2:" << count_numbers(array, 2) << ",3:" << count_numbers(array, 3) << ",4:" << count_numbers(array, 4) << ",5:" << count_numbers(array, 5) << ",6:" << count_numbers(array, 6) <<",7:" << count_numbers(array, 7) << ",8:" << count_numbers(array, 8) << ",9:" << count_numbers(array, 9) << std::endl;
}
```

PS. Ignore incorrect indentation its just from pasting to this site

PPS. Thanks for any assistance.

*****EDIT*****
Thank you "Vlad From Moscow" for the assistance.
My initial (terrible) code would have worked if I'd simply removed the (unintentional) `count_number(array);` call from `main.cpp`

However the for loop system proposed by Vlad allowed me to shrink the code by 80%. It now looks like this:

```
int count_numbers(int array[4][4], int Q)
{
int ans=0;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
        ans += array[i][j] ==Q;
    }
}
return ans;
}
```

Thank you for the assistance which was great, I began coding on Python so it was my lack of understanding of loops in C++ which was the real problem here.
Anyway, problem solved..

Comment: This code would be vastly improved if you used an array instead of the named variables zero - nine...

Comment: count_numbers takes two arguments but you are just passing one to it and also in your function all of the branches should have a return so you should add another return just before the final } of the function

Comment: Ouch ! This is reaaally not a good approach to the problem. Advices: use standard library containers (std::vector or here std::array). And you don't need to store the counters in separate variable, just put that in `std::array<int,10>`

Comment: `Ignore incorrect indentation` No. It's your job to provide a correctly formatted code. Paste code, select, then CTRL-K.

Comment: those ifs can be replaced simply by `digit[array[X][Y]]++`

Answer (score 3):

This call

```
count_numbers(array);
```

does not make sense and moreover is invalid because the function requires two arguments instead of one.

The function itself can be written the following way

```
const size_t N = 4;

size_t count_number( const int ( &a )[N][N], int value )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            n += a[i][j] == value;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

and called like

```
std::cout << "0: "   << count_number( array, 0 ) 
          << ", 1: " << count_number( array, 1 ) 
          << ", 2: " << count_number( array, 2 ) 
          << ", 3: " << count_number( array, 3 ) 
          << ", 4: " << count_number( array, 4 ) 
          << ", 5: " << count_number( array, 5 ) 
          << ", 6: " << count_number( array, 6 ) 
          << ", 7: " << count_number( array, 7 ) 
          << ", 8: " << count_number( array, 8 ) 
          << ", 9: " << count_number( array, 9 ) 
          << std::endl;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t N = 4;

size_t count_number( const int ( &a )[N][N], int value )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            n += a[i][j] == value;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int array[N][N] = 
    { 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 } , 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 } , 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 } , 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 } 
    };

    bool first = true;
    for ( int value = 0; value < 10; ++value )
    {
        size_t n = count_number( array, value );

        if ( n )
        {
            std::cout << ( first ? first = false, "" : ", " )
                      << value << ": "  << n; 
        }
    }        
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Its output is

```
1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4
```

A more general approach can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename InputIterator, typename T>
size_t count_number( InputIterator first, 
                     InputIterator last, 
                     const T &value )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        n += std::count( std::begin( *first ), std::end( *first ), value );
    }        

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 4;
    int array[N][N] = 
    { 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 } , 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 } , 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 } , 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 } 
    };

    bool first = true;
    for ( int value = 0; value < 10; ++value )
    {
        size_t n = count_number( std::begin( array ), std::end( array ), value );

        if ( n )
        {
            std::cout << ( first ? first = false, "" : ", " )
                      << value << ": "  << n; 
        }
    }        
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output will be the same as it is shown above.

If the array contains only digits that you need to count then the function can look like

```
const size_t N = 4;

void count_digits( const int ( &a )[N][N], size_t ( &digits)[10] )
{
    for ( size_t &x : digits ) x = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            ++digits[a[i][j]];
        }
    }
}
```

To call the function you need to declare in main an array like for example

```
size_t digits[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can return `int[]` or event better since you are using c++ return `vector<int>`.

In your function you can replace one, two, .. with something like

```
vector<int> result(10);
```

This will create a vector with 10 entries, all of them 0.
Then replace thing like `three = three + 1` with `result[3] = result[3] + 1` or even more condensed `result[3]++`

Then at the end you can write `... << ",0:" << result[0] << ...` or even do a for loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) count << "," << i << ":" << result[i];
```

You can do all this with `int[]` as well if that's required but you need to take care of allocating and deallocating the memory. `vector` will simplify your code a lot.